# how to check view associated with which controller ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I just get assigned to a ASP MVC project.
It has lots of controllers and lots of views...
I am getting confused abt which view is associated with which method of a controller ?

How to check which controller and method is associated with view ? 
or 
for which controller view has been added ?

Answer (score 4):

Right click from the view; select go to controller

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the view of a method in a controller, right click on the method name. That is if `public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl)` is your method of a controller, right click on the `Index`, then you can see the option `Go To View`. Click on that to go to the view of that method. Hope this helps..

Comment: I want to know the reverse process, I want to know the controller and its method associated using view file...

Comment: Under 'Views' folder in your solution, you can find sub folder of 'controller'. Inside each controller folder, you can find 'views'. Most of the time, view name is the same name of the method in the controller with the corresponding 'controller' folder name. Got it?

Comment: For example, in your 'Views' folder, there might be a controller folder, say 'Home'. Inside that 'Home' folder you can see views named '_Login.cshtml,_Index.cshtml' etc. This name of the view, i.e. _Login is the method name in Home controller.

Answer (score 2):

Well,
ASP.NET MVC, follows a "convention over configuration" thumb rule.

so unless you have configured something special in your project, it should follow a convention.

The convention is, every controller action would have a view with the same name.
I.e. If we have a controller of name "Users" with a controller method, 
public ActionResult MyView()
then the corresponding View would be named MyView.aspx or MyView.shtml or MyView.cshtml inside a folder named "Users".

hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is many way to create URL in MVC. 
1 Configure Route in a file and assign controller name and action 
2 you can check URL and find the Controller and action. ie. http://www.abc.com/customer/address In this Controller name is "customer" and action name is "address"

Using action name, you can find View name is define or not if there is no view name its means view name is similar with action name under controller name folder.